# why is the task cards going back to the to do column after i refresh?

Tags: javascript, kanban

So this is basically a kanban progress board, but my problem is that when I create a task and drag and drop it to other columns, it just goes back to the first column after refreshing. I cant find where it went wrong...

I tried making chatgpt fix it but i think he added things i dont understand.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Do It!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="png" href="doit-removebg-preview.png">
    
    <!-- Font Awesome Cdn Link -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04558dcba4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- POP UP PAG DRINAG -->
    <div class="popup-box">
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="content">
                <header>
                    <p>New Task</p>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
                </header>
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="row title">
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <input id="title" placeholder="Enter your to-do here">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row description">
                        <label for="desc">Description</label>
                        <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Provide additional details..."></textarea>
                    </div>



                    <div class="row dropdown">
                        <label>Tags</label>

                        <div class="btn-radio" id="radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="radio"/>
                            <label for="radio01"><span><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>Personal</span></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="btn-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="radio" />
                            <label for="radio02"><span><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>Work</span></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="btn-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio03" name="radio" />
                            <label for="radio03"><span><i class="fas fa-book"></i>School</span></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="btn-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="radio04" name="radio" />
                            <label for="radio04"><span><i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>Coding</span></label>
                          </div>
                        
                      </div>
                    <button>Add Task</button>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
<!-- DONE DRAG -->




    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="logo">
            <h2><img src="doit.png" class="logoimg"><span>DoIt!</span></h2>
        </div>
        
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="dash">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="personal" id="personal" draggable="true">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>
                    <span>Personal</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="work">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>
                    <span>Work</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="school">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
                    <span>School</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="coding">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
                    <span>Coding</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="logout">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
                    <span>Log out</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- main sa right -->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="header-title">
                <h2>Home</h2>
            </div>
            <img src="rimuru.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
   
        <!-- BUTTON PARA SA ADD -->
        <div class="addBox">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
            <p>Add Task</p>
        </div>

        <div class="kanban-board">
            <!-- To Do Column -->
<div class="kanban-column" id="todo-column">
    <h5>To do</h5>
    <div class="kanban-cards" id="todo-cards"></div>
</div>

<!-- In Progress Column -->
<div class="kanban-column in-progress" id="inprogress-column">
    <h5>In progress</h5>
    <div class="kanban-cards" id="inprogress-cards"></div>
</div>

<!-- Completed Column -->
<div class="kanban-column" id="completed-column">
    <h5>Completed</h5>
    <div class="kanban-cards" id="completed-cards"></div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;500;600&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  background: #f8f0ff;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 1.7rem;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  background: white;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  
}

.sidebar:hover{
  width: 240px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu {
  height: 88%;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  
}

.menu li {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.logo {
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right:1rem;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #69665C;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  
}

.logoimg {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.logo h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dash:hover, .dash{
  background-color: #FFF9DE;
}

.personal:hover, #personal:active{
  background-color: #D2CEFF;
}

.work:hover, .work:active{
  background-color: #D1E5F7;
}

.school:hover, .school:active{
  background-color: #FFCECE;
}

.coding:hover, .coding:active{
  background-color: #DAF2D6;
}

.logout:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.logout:hover span{
  color: white;
}

.menu a {
  color: #69665C;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.menu a span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu a i {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.fas.fa-user {
  color: #FFB843;
}

.fas.fa-clipboard {
  color: #7875A9;
}

.fas.fa-folder-open {
  color: #7DA9D6;
}

.fas.fa-book {
  color: #FF8E8E;
}

.fas.fa-laptop-code {
  color: #7BC683;
}

.fa-solid.fa-arrow-right-from-bracket {
  color: red;
}

.logout {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */
/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */
/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */

.main
{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #69665C;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 2rem;
}

.header-wrapper img {
  max-width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}



/* /////MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */
/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */
/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/*yung notes*/
/* Add this CSS for the to-do cards */
.todo-card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.todo-card-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 280px;
}

.todo-card-footer {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.todo-card-header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 260px; 
}

.delete-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}
.fas.fa-trash {
  color: red;
}
.todo-text {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* POP UP PAG INADD */
.popup-box{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 999;
  color: #69665C;
}

.popup-box .popup{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  justify-content: center ;


}

.popup-box, .popup-box .popup {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.popup-box.show, .popup-box.show .popup {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.popup .content {
  background: lavender;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  
}

.popup .content header {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #69665C;
  
}

.content header p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content header i{
  color: #69665C;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.content header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content form {
  margin: 15px 25px 20px;
 
}
.content form .row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

form .row label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.content form :where(input, textarea, select){
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content form textarea {
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

.content form button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background: #5D5A8C;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.popup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* ADD TASK */
.addBox {
  margin: 1rem 0;

  background: #7875A9;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center; 
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addBox:hover {
  background: #5D5A8C;
}

.addBox:active {
  transform: scale(1.01);
}


.add i {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.add p {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
/* ADD TASK TAPOS */




/* tags */
.btn-radio {
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.btn-radio input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}

.btn-radio input[type="radio"] + label span{
    display:inline-block;
    
    height:100%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    
    padding: 3px 7px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:  5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;

}
.btn-radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label span{
  background-color: #ccc;
}


.btn-radio i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/* Kanban Board */
.kanban-board {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.kanban-column {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  
}


.kanban-column h5{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #69665C;
  color: #69665C;
}

.kanban-cards {
  min-height: 500px; /* Adjust the minimum height as needed */
  
}



/* Kanban Card */


.kanban-card {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
}

.kanban-card .kanban-card-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: calc(100% - 24px);
  position: relative;
}

.kanban-card-actions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}



.kanban-card h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Style the edit icon within the .icons div */
.kanban-card h4 .icons .edit-icon {
  color: #7b83a4; /* Change the color as needed */
  margin-right: 5px;
}

/* Style the delete icon within the .icons div */
.kanban-card h4 .icons .delete-icon {
  color: red; /* Change the color as needed */
}

.kanban-card p {
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.kanban-card-tag {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* Define different styles for different card tags */
.kanban-card.tag-Personal {
  border-left: 3px solid #7875A9;
  
}

.kanban-card.tag-Work {
  border-left: 3px solid #7DA9D6;
}

.kanban-card.tag-School {
  border-left: 3px solid #FF8E8E;
}

.kanban-card.tag-Coding {
  border-left: 3px solid #7BC683;
}

/* Card Dragging Styles */
.kanban-card.is-dragging {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Card Placeholder Styles */
.kanban-card-placeholder {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 150px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

js

```
const addBox = document.querySelector(".addBox");
const popupBox = document.querySelector(".popup-box");
const closeIcon = popupBox.querySelector("header i");
const titleTag = popupBox.querySelector("#title");
const descTag = popupBox.querySelector("#desc");
const addBtn = popupBox.querySelector("button");
const kanbanColumns = document.querySelectorAll(".kanban-column");
let selectedTag = "Personal";
let selectedTagColor = "#7875A9";
const tagColors = {
  Personal: "#7875A9",
  Work: "#7DA9D6",
  School: "#FF8E8E",
  Coding: "#7BC683",
};


let notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || [];

function loadTasksFromLocalStorage() {
  // Clear existing cards
  kanbanColumns.forEach((column) => {
    column.querySelector(".kanban-cards").innerHTML = "";
  });

  // Load tasks from localStorage
  notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) || [];

  // Create cards based on loaded tasks
  notes.forEach((task) => {
    createKanbanCard(task);
  });
}




window.addEventListener("load", loadTasksFromLocalStorage);

addBox.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popupBox.classList.add("show");
});

closeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popupBox.classList.remove("show");
});

function deleteKanbanCard(cardId) {
  const cardToDelete = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${cardId}"]`);
  if (cardToDelete) {
    cardToDelete.remove();
  }

  notes = notes.filter((task) => task.id !== cardId);
  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(notes));
}

function createKanbanCard(task) {
  const { title, description, tag, tagColor, status, id } = task;
  const card = document.createElement("div");
  const tagClassName = `tag-${tag.replace(/\s/g, "-")}`; // Replace spaces with hyphens
  card.classList.add("kanban-card");
  card.classList.add(tagClassName);
  card.draggable = true;
  card.dataset.tag = tag;
  card.dataset.id = id || generateUniqueId();

  const cardTemplate = `
    <h4>${title}<div class="icons">
      <i class="fas fa-edit edit-icon"></i> 
      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete-icon" onclick="deleteKanbanCard('${id}')"></i>
    </div></h4>
    <p>${description}</p>
    <div class="kanban-card-tag" style="background-color: ${tagColor}">${tag}</div>
  `;

  card.innerHTML = cardTemplate;

  // Inside createKanbanCard function
const targetColumn = Array.from(kanbanColumns).find(
  (column) => column.querySelector("h5").textContent.trim() === tag
);

if (targetColumn) {
  // Set the initial status based on the target column
  const newStatus = targetColumn.querySelector("h5").textContent.trim();
  task.status = newStatus;
  
  targetColumn.querySelector(".kanban-cards").appendChild(card);
} else {
  const todoColumn = kanbanColumns[0];
  todoColumn.querySelector(".kanban-cards").appendChild(card);
}


  card.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", card.dataset.id);
  });
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let noteTitle = titleTag.value;
  let noteDesc = descTag.value;

  if (selectedTag && (noteTitle || noteDesc)) {
    const newTask = {
  id: generateUniqueId(),
  title: noteTitle,
  description: noteDesc,
  tag: selectedTag, // This is the tag name (e.g., "Personal")
  tagColor: selectedTagColor,
  status: "To do", // Initial status when the task is created
};


    notes.push(newTask);
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(notes));

    createKanbanCard(newTask);
    titleTag.value = "";
    descTag.value = "";
    closeIcon.click();
  } else {
    alert("Please select a tag and fill in the title or description.");
  }
});

kanbanColumns.forEach((column) => {
  column.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    column.classList.add("hover");
  });

  column.addEventListener("dragleave", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    column.classList.remove("hover");
  });

  column.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Inside the drop event listener
    const cardId = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    const draggedCard = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${cardId}"]`);
    if (draggedCard) {
      column.querySelector(".kanban-cards").appendChild(draggedCard);
    
      const newStatus = column.querySelector("h5").textContent.trim();
      const updatedTask = notes.find((task) => task.id === cardId);
      if (updatedTask) {
        updatedTask.status = newStatus; // Update the status property
        localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(notes)); // Save the updated tasks
      }
    }
    

kanbanColumns.forEach((col) => col.classList.remove("hover"));

  });
});

const tagRadioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio"]');

tagRadioButtons.forEach((radio) => {
  radio.addEventListener("click", () => {
    selectedTag = radio.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim();
    selectedTagColor = tagColors[selectedTag];
    
  });
});

function generateUniqueId() {
  return Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
}
```

Comment: In the drop call back function you use the `find()` function to find a task. You always get `undefined` because the id from the event (text/plain) is a string, not an number. Do `const cardId = parseInt(e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"));`. I don't know if you have other errors like this.